# SwiftUI: Aligning views to the leading & trailing edges of another view in a VStack

Tags: ios, layout, alignment, swiftui

How do you align content to the leading and trailing edges of another view in a SwiftUI `VStack`?

I currently have the following SwiftUI code:

```swift
struct MyBlock: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.gray).frame(width: 80, height: 80)
    }
}

struct MyGridView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 16) {
            MyBlock()
            MyBlock()
            MyBlock()
        }                       
    }
}

struct PinPad: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyGridView()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Left Align") })
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Right Align") })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result renders like this:

[image: Spacer consumes all the available space]

But what I really want is for the `"Left Align"` `Button` to align with the left/leading edge of `MyGridView` and the `"Right Align"` `Button` to align to the right/trailing edge of the `MyGridView`.

Eg, like this:

[image: Aligned Buttons]

I'm obviously missing something very basic here as doing this with Auto-Layout in UIKit is trivial.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first thing you need to do to troubleshoot layout issues, is to add borders on the views. This will let you see the real (and invisible) bounds of your views. The problem will become more clear:

[image]

In your case it can be easily fixed by wrapping it all inside a HStack and add some spacers:

[image]

```swift
struct PinPad: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                MyGridView().border(Color.blue, width: 3)
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Left Align") }).border(Color.red, width: 3)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Right Align") }).border(Color.red, width: 3)
                }
            }.border(Color.green, width: 3)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly works. I'll give that a go for now unless someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

`GeometryReader` is a view that gives you access to the size and position of your parent

Defined a view called GeometryGetter,

```
struct GeometryGetter: View {

    @Binding var rect: CGRect

    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.makeView(geometry: geometry)
        }
    }

    func makeView(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        }

        return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

Then change your code as below,

```
struct PinPad: View {

    @State private var rect: CGRect = CGRect()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                MyGridView().background(GeometryGetter(rect: $rect))
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Left Align") })
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Right Align") })
                }.frame(width: rect.width)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `.fixedSize()` to your VStack solves the problem.

```
struct PinPad: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyGridView()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Left Align") })
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Right Align") })
            }
        }
        .fixedSize()
    }
}
```

**Brief Explanation:**

> Basic thing about autolayout, in swiftui depends upon the frame of
> different stack of Stacks we use. As in this query, first VStack is
> the parent view, which wrapped around its childView for its frame as
> it is explicitly provided. But, due to the HStack of buttons which
> doesn't have any explicitly width provided but due to the `Spacer()`;
> (which explicitly made the buttons drag to their edges), HStack's
> frame had width of size of screen available, which made the parent
> VStack view to get enlarged as well along with it. Thus, we need to
> pay attention to the sub-views frame as well, along with the parent
> view.
>
> **Extra info:-** Adding `alignment:` to the stacks itself will only align the content within that view, while adding `.frame(alignment:)` modifier will align the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could add .fixedSize() after the VStack.